# jQuery to select all unanswered multiple choice question

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

could you help me pls.

I need a jquery code to select all unanswered question in a multiple choice test.
The Multiple choice questions are of 3 types:
(1) Single Answer
(2) Multiple Answer
(3) Yes / No Answer

By selecting, i mean to make the background of the question/answer another color, on clicking on a checkbox "Show Unanswered Questions"

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div>
            <input id="unansweredquestion" type="checkbox" name="uquestion" /><label for="unansweredquestion"> Show Unanswered Questions</label>
        <div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <strong>
                    Question
                    <span id="maincontent_lvTest_lblRowNumber_0">1</span>
                </strong>
                <div style="float: right">
                    <input id="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBox1_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl0$CheckBox1" /><label for="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBox1_0"> Doubtful</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">
                    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl0$hfQuesId" id="maincontent_lvTest_hfQuesId_0" value="3088" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl0$hfQuestionType" id="maincontent_lvTest_hfQuestionType_0" value="2" />
                    <span id="maincontent_lvTest_lblQuestiontext_0">Who created the World?</span>
                </h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                    <table id="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0_0_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl0$CheckBoxList1$0" value="2169" /><label for="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0_0_0">Extraterrestrial Being</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0_1_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl0$CheckBoxList1$1" value="2167" /><label for="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0_1_0">God</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0_2_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl0$CheckBoxList1$2" value="2168" /><label for="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0_2_0">Man</label></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <strong>
                    Question
                    <span id="maincontent_lvTest_lblRowNumber_1">2</span>
                </strong>
                <div style="float: right">
                    <input id="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBox1_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl1$CheckBox1" /><label for="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBox1_1"> Doubtful</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">
                    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl1$hfQuesId" id="maincontent_lvTest_hfQuesId_1" value="3116" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl1$hfQuestionType" id="maincontent_lvTest_hfQuestionType_1" value="3" />
                    <span id="maincontent_lvTest_lblQuestiontext_1">Is the Earth round?</span>
                </h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                    <table id="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList2_1">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList2_1_0_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl1$RadioButtonList2" value="2336" /><label for="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList2_1_0_1">No</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList2_1_1_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl1$RadioButtonList2" value="2335" /><label for="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList2_1_1_1">Yes</label></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <strong>
                    Question
                    <span id="maincontent_lvTest_lblRowNumber_2">3</span>
                </strong>
                <div style="float: right">
                    <input id="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBox1_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl2$CheckBox1" /><label for="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBox1_2"> Doubtful</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">

                    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl2$hfQuesId" id="maincontent_lvTest_hfQuesId_2" value="3082" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl2$hfQuestionType" id="maincontent_lvTest_hfQuestionType_2" value="1" />
                    <span id="maincontent_lvTest_lblQuestiontext_2">Who wrote "The man is the man"?</span>
                </h5>
                <p class="card-text">

                    <table id="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList1_2">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList1_2_0_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl2$RadioButtonList1" value="2134" /><label for="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList1_2_0_2">Ryan</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList1_2_1_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl2$RadioButtonList1" value="2132" /><label for="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList1_2_1_2">Daudet</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList1_2_2_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl2$RadioButtonList1" value="2133" /><label for="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList1_2_2_2">Claude</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList1_2_3_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl2$RadioButtonList1" value="2131" /><label for="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList1_2_3_2">Alphone</label></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks

Tairon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I minfied your html and added a class for `.answers` to the table. Also I moved the `input` into the `label`. Now this little example will show you how to do it.

**Edited the code after last comment**

I've modified the jQuery section for your described case in the comments. Now it's possible to create multiple questions/answers on one page if needed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#unansweredquestion').on('change', toggleUnansweredQuestions);
  $('.answers input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', toggleUnansweredQuestions);

  function toggleUnansweredQuestions(event) {
    var toggleCheckbox = $('#unansweredquestion');
    var answers = $('.answers');

    if (toggleCheckbox.prop('checked')) {
      answers.each(function(index, answer) {
        var $answer = $(answer);
        var hasAnswers = $answer.find('input:checked').length > 0;

        if (hasAnswers) {
          $answer.removeClass('highlighted');
        } else {
          $answer.addClass('highlighted');
        }
      });
    } else {
      answers.removeClass('highlighted');
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.highlighted { background-color: #f00; color: #0f0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="unansweredquestion">
  <input id="unansweredquestion" type="checkbox" name="uquestion" /> Show Unanswered Questions
</label>

<table id="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0" class="answers">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0_0_0">
        <input id="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0_0_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl0$CheckBoxList1$0" value="2169" /> Extraterrestrial Being
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0_1_0">
        <input id="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0_1_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl0$CheckBoxList1$1" value="2167" /> God
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0_2_0">
        <input id="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0_2_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl0$CheckBoxList1$2" value="2168" /> Man
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi UfguFugullu, this is working for the table your modify, but pls note that Asp.net is generating my code as per what i posted. could you please amend your code as to meet the one i posted. Thxx. tairon

Comment: @Tairon You just have to made the one change with the class. I'm very sure that you can add the class answers to your table even with ASP.Net. If not, change the selector '.answer' to something that fit to your markup like 'table'

Comment: Hi UfguFugullu, I am trying to modify the code u give me, its working fine except one thing. when i select any item of the checkbox, all the checkbox for this question need not be highlighted. when no checkbox is selected, the checkbox need to be highlighted again. thanks .. tairon

Comment: @Tairon I've modified the code for your described case

Comment: Thank UfguFugullu, it work great. I am new to jQuery, could you please guide me on where i can learn jQuery. (any website, tutorial, video). thank again

Comment: @Tairon I've learned it by myself with much of researching about google and stackoverflow. All information about using jQuery can be found here https://api.jquery.com/. But if you are looking for a simple tutorial, you should find it here https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

Answer (score 0):

- add a class name as, "question" to the questions card
- add a class name as, "answer" to the answers.
- add a class to change the background on unanswered questions check box is triggered

Code:

```css
.unanswered {
            background: azure;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="maincontent_UpdatePanel1">
            <div>
                <input id="unansweredquestion" type="checkbox" name="uquestion" /><label for="unansweredquestion"> Show
                    Unanswered Questions</label>
                <div>
                    <div class="card question">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <strong>
                                Question
                                <span id="maincontent_lvTest_lblRowNumber_0">1</span>
                            </strong>
                            <div style="float: right">
                                <input id="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBox1_0" type="checkbox"
                                    name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl0$CheckBox1" /><label
                                    for="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBox1_0"> Doubtful</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">
                                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl0$hfQuesId"
                                    id="maincontent_lvTest_hfQuesId_0" value="3088" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl0$hfQuestionType"
                                    id="maincontent_lvTest_hfQuestionType_0" value="2" />
                                <span id="maincontent_lvTest_lblQuestiontext_0">Who created the World?</span>
                            </h5>
                            <p class="card-text">
                                <table id="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input id="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0_0_0" type="checkbox"
                                                name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl0$CheckBoxList1$0" value="2169"
                                                class="answer" /><label
                                                for="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0_0_0">Extraterrestrial
                                                Being</label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input id="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0_1_0" type="checkbox"
                                                name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl0$CheckBoxList1$1" value="2167"
                                                class="answer" /><label
                                                for="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0_1_0">God</label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input id="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0_2_0" type="checkbox"
                                                name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl0$CheckBoxList1$2" value="2168"
                                                class="answer" /><label
                                                for="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBoxList1_0_2_0">Man</label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="card question">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <strong>
                                Question
                                <span id="maincontent_lvTest_lblRowNumber_1">2</span>
                            </strong>
                            <div style="float: right">
                                <input id="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBox1_1" type="checkbox"
                                    name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl1$CheckBox1" /><label
                                    for="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBox1_1"> Doubtful</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">
                                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl1$hfQuesId"
                                    id="maincontent_lvTest_hfQuesId_1" value="3116" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl1$hfQuestionType"
                                    id="maincontent_lvTest_hfQuestionType_1" value="3" />
                                <span id="maincontent_lvTest_lblQuestiontext_1">Is the Earth round?</span>
                            </h5>
                            <p class="card-text">
                                <table id="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList2_1">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input id="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList2_1_0_1" type="radio"
                                                name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl1$RadioButtonList2" value="2336"
                                                class="answer" /><label
                                                for="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList2_1_0_1">No</label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input id="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList2_1_1_1" type="radio"
                                                name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl1$RadioButtonList2" value="2335"
                                                class="answer" /><label
                                                for="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList2_1_1_1">Yes</label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card question">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <strong>
                                Question
                                <span id="maincontent_lvTest_lblRowNumber_2">3</span>
                            </strong>
                            <div style="float: right">
                                <input id="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBox1_2" type="checkbox"
                                    name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl2$CheckBox1" /><label
                                    for="maincontent_lvTest_CheckBox1_2"> Doubtful</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">

                                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl2$hfQuesId"
                                    id="maincontent_lvTest_hfQuesId_2" value="3082" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl2$hfQuestionType"
                                    id="maincontent_lvTest_hfQuestionType_2" value="1" />
                                <span id="maincontent_lvTest_lblQuestiontext_2">Who wrote "The man is the man"?</span>
                            </h5>
                            <p class="card-text">

                                <table id="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList1_2">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input id="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList1_2_0_2" type="radio"
                                                name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl2$RadioButtonList1" value="2134"
                                                class="answer" /><label
                                                for="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList1_2_0_2">Ryan</label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input id="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList1_2_1_2" type="radio"
                                                name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl2$RadioButtonList1" value="2132"
                                                class="answer" /><label
                                                for="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList1_2_1_2">Daudet</label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input id="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList1_2_2_2" type="radio"
                                                name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl2$RadioButtonList1" value="2133"
                                                class="answer" /><label
                                                for="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList1_2_2_2">Claude</label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input id="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList1_2_3_2" type="radio"
                                                name="ctl00$maincontent$lvTest$ctrl2$RadioButtonList1" value="2131"
                                                class="answer" /><label
                                                for="maincontent_lvTest_RadioButtonList1_2_3_2">Alphone</label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```js
$("document").ready(function () {
    getAllUnansweredQuestions();
    toggleUnanswered();
});

function getAllUnansweredQuestions() {
    $('#unansweredquestion').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            const questions = $('.question');

            questions.each(function () {
                if (!$(this).find('.answer').is(':checked')) {
                    $(this).addClass('unanswered');
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('.question').removeClass('unanswered')
        }
    });
}

function toggleUnanswered() {
    $('.answer').on('change', function () {
        const isChecked = ($(this).is(":checked"));

        if ($('#unansweredquestion').is(":checked")) {
            if (isChecked) {
                $(this).offsetParent().removeClass('unanswered');
            } else {
                $(this).offsetParent().addClass('unanswered');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Lasanga Guruge, It look good. But when i unselect all the checkbox for a question, the question need to be hightlighted again as unanswered. could you pls amend the code. thx. tairon

Comment: @Tairon Added toggling functionality